# Web server end user monitoring

Tags: users, network-monitoring

I am searching for a solution to monitor access and activities on my web server. There are only a handful of people who are allowed to access my https or ftp/sftp server and I would like to know:

Who is on
What does he/she do
Which files do they upload 
which files do they download

I am not interested in speed or other technical information.

I hope someone can help as I have searched the web now for several days without success...

Thanks in advance
Lutz

Comment: Hi - thanks again but isn´t there an easier/less complex tool/method available? I only want to see which person is on the server (only registered users know the hostname of my file server) - best would be something like a "Skype-screen"

A screen which gives me instant information if someone logs on or of.... I think the server will recognise this event and the only thing I want is that it is shown on my screen.

Thanks again
Lutz

Answer (score 0):

All you really want is a log analyzer.

For the web, if the logs are in [CLF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) format (i.e., [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) etc) then [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/) is the most commonly used.  If you use an FTP server that also uses CLF format logging then [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/) should also handle that as well.

Comment: First of all thanks!Honestly I am not very familiar with these crypts... is there a GUI which will give me more a visual information (also over a longer period of time)

Comment: by the way - I run a linkstation duo 2 TB accessable with https and sftp

Comment: Webalizer parses log files and creates a pretty web page with graphs and such on it.

Answer (score 0):

Awstats is a good solution too.